# Blender freezing when I try to add automatic weights to a parent?

Tags: armature

still very new to Blender, and I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU) for creating rigging to a character model.
At around the 10:12 mark, we're instructed to hit Crtl+P while selecting both the armature & the mesh, and clicking on "Set Parent to...Armature Deform...with Automatic Weights". Upon doing this, my software immediately freezes, and I can no longer continue the project. Considering the fact I have a really nice setup, I don't think it's my video card persay, I'm curious what's causing Blender to freeze up. I'm not sure how I can continue from here. (The screenshot is my current model, where I'm trying to apply the step explained)

[image: This is the screenshot of my current Blender model, where I'm trying to follow the steps explained in the tutorial, upon clicking on "with automatic weights, the program freezes and quits.]

So, what am I doing wrong? Is my current character model too complex? I noticed the leg bones stick out of the leg mesh slightly, is that the problem? Or did I miss something else entirely?
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: 870000 vertices, your mesh is very high poly, this makes blender freeze

Comment: In your screenshot it looks like only the armature is selected. That said, that shouldn't cause blender to freeze.. If your mesh has a lot of polygons, blender may take a while to compute the weights, which will make blender appear frozen until the process is complete. How long have you waited to see if blender unfreezes? Ideally you would weight a lower-poly model, then use a subsurf modifier after the armature modifier to increase the resolution.